# Why does introducing value of variable for NDSolve via function not work for this problem?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, broken-code

I am very confused and even restarted Kernel several times (Mathematica 13.1 Windows 10). However, I fail to understand why one evaluation of `NDSolve` works while a similar implementation in which I introduce the value of a scalar variable `LK` into the equation via function definition does not work.

This works

```
dP = 17.48;
c0 = -4.0;
LK = -39.9968;

First@NDSolve[{c'[s] - (-2 d[s] Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2])/f[s] == 0, 
   f'[s] - 4 Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2] == 0, 
   d'[s] - (-(2 c[s]^2 (d[s] - c0) + c[s] (c0^2 - d[s]^2) + LK*c[s] + 
          dP + 4 d[s] (1 - f[s] c[s]^2)/f[s]))/(Sqrt[
       1 - f[s] c[s]^2]) == 0, f[0.0005] == 0.0001, 
   c[0.0005] == -0.50, d[0.0005] == 0.0001}, {c, f, d}, {s, 0.0005, 0.5}]
```

But this does not

```
dP = 17.48;
c0 = -4.0;

psol[LK_?NumericQ] := 
 First@NDSolve[{c'[s] - (-2 d[s] Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2])/f[s] == 0, 
    f'[s] - 4 Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2] == 0, 
    d'[s] - (-(2 c[s]^2 (d[s] - c0) + c[s] (c0^2 - d[s]^2) + LK*c[s] +
            dP + 4 d[s] (1 - f[s] c[s]^2)/f[s]))/(Sqrt[
        1 - f[s] c[s]^2]) == 0, f[0.0005] == 0.0001, 
    c[0.0005] == -0.50, d[0.0005] == 0.0001}, {c, f, d}, {s, 0.0005, 0.5}]

psol[-33.9968]
```

Does anyone experience the same issue? What am I possibly doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)
```

Your second method evaluates very much more slowly, stops evaluating at about `s = 0.433`, and gives erroneous results.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dP = 17.48;
c0 = -4.0;

psol[LK_?NumericQ] := 
 First@NDSolve[{c'[s] - (-2 d[s] Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2])/f[s] == 0, 
    f'[s] - 4 Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2] == 0, 
    d'[s] - (-(2 c[s]^2 (d[s] - c0) + c[s] (c0^2 - d[s]^2) + LK*c[s] + dP + 
           4 d[s] (1 - f[s] c[s]^2)/f[s]))/(Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2]) == 0, 
    f[0.0005] == 0.0001, c[0.0005] == -0.50, d[0.0005] == 0.0001}, {c, f, 
    d}, {s, 0.0005, 0.5}]

psol[-33.9968] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Assuming that this reflects a precision issue, increase the precision handling by using exact values for all constants.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dP = 1748/100;
c0 = -4;

psol[LKv_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{LK = Rationalize[LKv, 0]}, 
  NDSolve[{c'[s] - (-2 d[s] Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2])/f[s] == 0, 
     f'[s] - 4 Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2] == 0, 
     d'[s] - (-(2 c[s]^2 (d[s] - c0) + c[s] (c0^2 - d[s]^2) + LK*c[s] + dP + 
            4 d[s] (1 - f[s] c[s]^2)/f[s]))/(Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2]) == 0, 
     f[5*^-4] == 10^-4, c[5*^-4] == -1/2, d[5*^-4] == 10^-4}, {c, f, d}, {s, 
     5*^-4, 1/2}] // First]

psol[-39.9968] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[{c[s], f[s], d[s]} /. psol[-39.9968]], 
  {s, 0.0005, 0.5},
 PlotLabels -> {c[s], f[s], d[s]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, did not notice that the issue was from numerical precision.

Answer (score 3):

it looks like a naming/scoping/buffering issue if you ask me. I can't answer why, but a simple workaround is the following. This is something that should be done anyway. Which is to define the ode and the IC as separate variables.

This makes the code easier to read also and maintain, and resolves this issue.

```
dP = 17.48;
c0 = -4.0;
LK = -39.9968;
ode = {c'[s] - (-2 d[s] Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2])/f[s] == 0, 
   f'[s] - 4 Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2] == 0, 
   d'[s] - (-(2 c[s]^2 (d[s] - c0) + c[s] (c0^2 - d[s]^2) + LK*c[s] + 
          dP + 4 d[s] (1 - f[s] c[s]^2)/f[s]))/(Sqrt[
        1 - f[s] c[s]^2]) == 0};
ic = {f[0.0005] == 0.0001, c[0.0005] == -0.50, d[0.0005] == 0.0001};

NDSolve[{ode, ic}, {c, f, d}, {s, 0.0005, 0.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the second one works with no problem

```
dP = 17.48;
c0 = -4.0;
psol[LK_?NumericQ] := First@NDSolve[{ode, ic}, {c, f, d}, {s, 0.0005, 0.5}]

psol[-33.9968]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Without doing the above, it still works, but takes much longer and gives

```
dP = 17.48;
c0 = -4.0;
psol[LK_?NumericQ] := 
 First@NDSolve[{c'[s] - (-2 d[s] Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2])/f[s] == 0, 
    f'[s] - 4 Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2] == 0, 
    d'[s] - (-(2 c[s]^2 (d[s] - c0) + c[s] (c0^2 - d[s]^2) + LK*c[s] +
            dP + 4 d[s] (1 - f[s] c[s]^2)/f[s]))/(Sqrt[
         1 - f[s] c[s]^2]) == 0, f[0.0005] == 0.0001, 
    c[0.0005] == -0.50, d[0.0005] == 0.0001}, {c, f, d}, {s, 0.0005, 
    0.5}]

psol[-33.9968]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

May be a bug.

Comment: I think if you do `Remove[Lk]` before your code then it does not work... dP = 17.48;
c0 = -4.0; psol[LK_?NumericQ] := First@NDSolve[{ode, ic}, {c, f, d}, {s, 0.0005, 0.5}]

psol[-33.9968] ... can you confirm?

Comment: @AliHashmi it works just fine. Why would removing LK causes a problem? Here is screen shot fyi  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOltY.png)  This is using 13.1 on windows 10

Comment: check this https://imgur.com/HE9i226

Comment: I just did ClearAll and Remove then added your code but did not define `LK` like the first time you defined it. I just cant seem to run the code. If you look at the output, LK stays undefined. I dont know what is happening on my end

Comment: I think you need to redefine `ode` after clearing or removing LK. because the ode still retains the value of -33.66 even after you clear variable `LK`.

Comment: @AliHashmi it is not biding the `LK` passed in to the `LK` in global context in the ode. May be NDSolve has holdAll on it. I do not know, But here is a workaround, just replace the definition of your function with `psol[lk_?NumericQ] := 
 NDSolve[{ode /. LK -> lk, ic}, {c, f, d}, {s, 0.0005, 0.5}]`  Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HmKL.png) but now it gives the same warning as before. So we back to square one. I do not like to mix functions like this, where some things defined globally and some are passed on. But I still think there is a bug....

Comment: ... it should work the same way in theory. But we are just giving workarounds here.

Comment: do you think it is worth reporting this to WRI as a bug?

Comment: @AliHashmi I think so. Because it _should_ have worked the same way in both cases. A workaround is just a workaround and does not fix or explain the core reason why it changes behavior when putting the NDSolve call inside a function.